# Android AVD on Eclipse4.03 api15 shows 'Blank Screen' with no activity

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I tried to run "hello world" program in android 4.03, but my **avd emulator** starts but gets stuck in a blank screen and doesn't show output

I got this warning also:

> Missing density variation folders in res: drawable-xhdpi

Please help me.

```
[2012-01-21 12:35:40 - helloworld] ------------------------------
[2012-01-21 12:35:40 - helloworld] Android Launch!
[2012-01-21 12:35:40 - helloworld] adb is running normally.
[2012-01-21 12:35:40 - helloworld] Performing com.man.Helloworld.HelloworldActivity   activity launch
[2012-01-21 12:35:40 - helloworld] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
 [2012-01-21 12:35:40 - helloworld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2012-01-21 12:35:46 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
 [2012-01-21 12:35:46 - helloworld] New emulator found: emulator-5554
 [2012-01-21 12:35:46 - helloworld] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning can be taken care of by creating a drawable resource folder for xhdpi like you have for ldpi, mdpi, and hdpi.

How long did you wait for the emulator to launch?  It is incredibly slow.